# Android Toolbar Popup menu not showing icons

Tags: android, android-menu, android-toolbar

I am trying to show a drop down menu for my toolbar which includes BOTH text and icons:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_add"
        android:title="@string/menu.add"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_edit"
        android:title="@string/menu.edit"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_create_black_24dp"
        app:showAsAction="never" />

</menu>
```

The menu_add does show with the icon on the toolbar itself but the menu_edit only shows the  text without the icon.

This answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19750717/197127 says that Google has removed it by design but does not refer to how you may override it.

### Edit

I also need the device "menu" button to show the same menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30337653/197127. Basically, overriding a method and it does not break the device menu button or the overflow. 
Thanks to all.

Answer (score 12):

I created something like this:

```
@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
fun Menu.showIcons() {
    (this as? MenuBuilder)?.setOptionalIconsVisible(true)
}
```

and it works basically on any menu.

For toolbar, you can override `onPrepareOptionsMenu` in activity or fragment and before calling `super` just call `menu.showIcons()` or you can use it with `PopupMenu` like so `PopupMenu(requireContext(), anchor).menu.showIcons()`.

Comment: I don't know why you didn't receive more upvotes. It's the only solution that worked for me, and it's the simplest of all.

Comment: This works in onCreateOptionsMenu too.

Answer (score 7):

This Kotlin code worked for me.
I used **"popup.setForceShowIcon(true)"**

val popup = PopupMenu(context, button);

popup.menuInflater.inflate(menuRes, popup.menu);

popup.setForceShowIcon(true)

**The full code is written below**

```
//R.menu.menu_popup -- Menu xml File
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_1"
        android:icon="@drawable/email"
        android:title="Email" />
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_2"
        android:icon="@drawable/phone"
        android:title="Phone" />
</menu>

// Inside Activity
findViewById<Button>(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener {
    show_PopUp_Menu(this, it, R.menu.menu_popup)
}


@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
fun show_PopUp_Menu(context: Context, button:Button, menuRes: Int) {

    val popup = PopupMenu(context, button)
    popup.menuInflater.inflate(menuRes, popup.menu)

    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener { menuItem: MenuItem ->
        when(menuItem.itemId){
            R.id.menu_1->{
                Toast.makeText(this, "Menu 1 clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                true
            }
            R.id.menu_2->{
                Toast.makeText(this, "Menu 2 clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                true
            }
            else -> false
        }
    }
    
    popup.setOnDismissListener {
        // Respond to popup being dismissed.
    }
    popup.setForceShowIcon(true)
    popup.show()
}
```

Comment: popup.setForceShowIcon(true) ::: Call requires API level 29 (current min is XX): android.widget.PopupMenu#setForceShowIcon

Answer (score 5):

Yes, its not being displayed in new versions of support library, but you can do the trick by adding submenu. (You can add it via both xml and code).
like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_menu_moreoverflow_mtrl_alpha"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="always">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_event"
                android:title="@string/action_settings"
                app:showAsAction="always" />
            <item
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_event"
                android:title="@string/action_settings"
                app:showAsAction="always" />
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

Hope it helped:)
Edit: see snapshots of above code:

[image: menu] => [image: menu open]

Comment: Thanks Harry. If I add it as a sub-menu of one of my items, I get an "in between" menu. I need it to open as the overflow.

Comment: See the snapshots, Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Yes. I need this to open once you click on the overflow button (the three vertical dots).

Comment: That's what I have showed you, this is output of the given code by me. Follow it properly.

Comment: Your are right for the top right menu. But it will not work if user clicks on the device menu button. Any idea?

Comment: That wasn't mentioned in question anyway.

Comment: The reason that I cannot accept this answer is that it breaks the function of the device menu button as it shows a skewed menu (it will now have submenus). Sorry.

Answer (score 4):

It doesnot work on android support v7 version but you can tweak this by modifying little bit. below code works for me

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_menu_moreoverflow_mtrl_alpha"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="always">
    <menu>

        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_rate"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_grade_black_24dp"
            android:orderInCategory="100"
            android:title="@string/action_rate"
            app:showAsAction="never" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_share"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_share_black_24dp"
            android:orderInCategory="101"
            android:title="@string/action_share"
            app:showAsAction="never" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_enquiry"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_message_black_24dp"
            android:orderInCategory="102"
            android:title="@string/action_enquiry"
            app:showAsAction="never" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_disclaimer"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_info_black_24dp"
            android:orderInCategory="103"
            android:title="@string/action_disclaimer"
            app:showAsAction="never" />
    </menu>
</item>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 MenuPopupHelper menuHelper = new MenuPopupHelper(getContext(), (MenuBuilder) 
 popupmenu.getMenu(), button);
 menuHelper.setForceShowIcon(true);
 menuHelper.show();
```

Worked for me.

Comment: what is that?? `MenuPopupHelper can only be called from within the same library group prefix`

Answer (score 0):

I created something like this:
Try this:

```
    Menu menu= toolbar.getMenu();
    Method menuMethod = null;
    try {
       menuMethod = menu.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setOptionalIconsVisible", Boolean.TYPE);
       menuMethod.setAccessible(true);
       menuMethod.invoke(menu, true);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From the Above 3.0 android icons in the pop menu are not displayed so you have to trick it and this works you can try

```
   //init the popup
   PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(context, anchor);
 
        /*  The below code in try catch is responsible to display icons*/
            try {
                Field[] fields = popup.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
                for (Field field : fields) {
                    if ("mPopup".equals(field.getName())) {
                        field.setAccessible(true);
                        Object menuPopupHelper = field.get(popup);
                        Class<?> classPopupHelper = Class.forName(menuPopupHelper.getClass().getName());
                        Method setForceIcons = classPopupHelper.getMethod("setForceShowIcon", boolean.class);
                        setForceIcons.invoke(menuPopupHelper, true);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
 
        //inflate menu
        popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, popup.getMenu());
 
        //show menu
        popup.show();
```