# 'onPrepareOptionsPanel(View?, Menu): Boolean' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java

Tags: android, kotlin, menu

I want to use this answer in Kotlin:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30337653/12478830

It works correctly for me but I get this warning **'onPrepareOptionsPanel(View?, Menu): Boolean' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java**. What should I use instead of it?

Answer (score 1):

From [the Android source code](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev:fragment/fragment/src/main/java/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentActivity.java;l=458?q=onPrepareOptionsPanel&sq=):

```java
/**
 * @hide
 * @deprecated Override {@link #onPreparePanel(int, View, Menu)}.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("DeprecatedIsStillUsed")
@RestrictTo(LIBRARY_GROUP_PREFIX)
@Deprecated
protected boolean onPrepareOptionsPanel(@Nullable View view, @NonNull Menu menu) {
    return super.onPreparePanel(Window.FEATURE_OPTIONS_PANEL, view, menu);
}
```

In other words you should use [`Activity.onPreparePanel(int, View, Menu)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onPreparePanel(int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.Menu)).

Comment: What about fragments? I can use this function in fragments?