# Can I show icon in overflow menu of Android Toolbar?

Tags: android

Please take in consideration that I'm refering to the Toolbar Widget(Android L/API 21+)
By overflow menu and icons I mean something like this one :

[image]

Something more difficult : Is there any way that the icons appear on the RIGHT side of the text?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

create a menu in menu, for example: main_activity_actions.xml
and use this code for the toolbar, try it:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:All4One="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/algo"//some id
        android:icon="@drawable/kami_nomi_zu_shiru_sekai3" //add the image
        android:title="nose"
        All4One:showAsAction="always">
        <menu>
            <item android:id="@+id/WIFI"//option to display on the menu
                android:icon="@drawable/nisekoi1"//this is a option of the submenu
                android:title="@string/WIFI"/>

            <item android:id="@+id/DATOS"
                android:icon="@drawable/nisekoi6" //this one also is a option
                android:title="@string/DATOS"/>

            <item android:id="@+id/BT"
                android:icon="@drawable/sao1"
                android:title="@string/BT"/>

            <item android:id="@+id/NADA"
                android:icon="@drawable/nisekoi6" //the same
                android:title="@string/NADA"/>
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

Comment: Great! Is there any way that the icons appear on the RIGHT side of the text? thx!

Comment: to the right side? mm.. i haven't try it, yet! jeje but maybe someone else knows it

Comment: There is a bit of an issue with this solution, If top level menu has enough icons that system itself decides to show overflow menu, we then have two overflow menus.

Comment: [How To show icons in Overflow menu in ActionBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18374183/how-to-show-icons-in-overflow-menu-in-actionbar)