# How To make this Button in Android App?

Tags: android

I want to know How To make icons just before the text in overflow menu in this photo and also how to make this share button. This Share Button Just share the text across whatsapp,google etc.

[Image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0gYnUjTCiZHTnFlSzE5U3hNbnc/view)

Answer (score 1):

To make an icon in a specific side of a `Button` you could use one of the attributes offered by the android SDK : [android:drawableBottom](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:drawableBottom), [android:drawableTop](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:drawableTop), [android:drawableLeft](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:drawableLeft), [android:drawableRight](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:drawableRight), [android:drawableStart](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:drawableStart) or [android:drawableEnd](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:drawableEnd)

**EDIT:** to make icon in overflow menu button you have to use the `android:icon` attribute to specify the icon's `drawable` reference and then add this attribute to force the button title to be shown `app:showAsAction="never|withText"`

Comment: <item
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/preferences"
        android:id="@+id/Preferences"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:title="NightMode"
        app:showAsAction="never" />      Nothing Works.

Comment: no , this works with `Button`s as I mentioned above, so you're talking about making icon in `ActionBar` menu ?? please try to be clear in you're question !! , in this case you have to use the `android:icon` attribute and `app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"`

Comment: Yes I want it in the overflow menu and I want to add icon in them, see the image i have attached

Comment: I have followed your suggestion but the output  I'm getting is this(image attached). But I want them in the overflow menu just like the image which I had attached in my question.

Comment: I have followed your suggestion but the output  I'm getting is this(image attached). But I want them in the overflow menu just like the image which I had attached in my question. OUTPUT - https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0gYnUjTCiZHRVpHelJoaGFXTlk/view?usp=sharing XML - https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0gYnUjTCiZHMURZZ3NUeDNZY0E/view?usp=sharing

Comment: you just have to replace `ifRoom` by `never` to force showing buttons only in the overflow menu

Comment: Ok now i have done what u had suggest but still not getting the image. OUTPUT - https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0gYnUjTCiZHVmVhVUgyRTR3b00/view?usp=sharing XML - https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0gYnUjTCiZHdHlWeU5CWTA3Wm8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Do I need to add something more to get the image. Do image size matters? I have the image of size 48X48

Comment: take a look at this answer it may helps : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18374183/how-to-show-icons-in-overflow-menu-in-actionbar/22288914#22288914 , I think cause you're working with android 5+ version this may not works but just make a try

Comment: I didn't even understand the question I know its not possible using the native API. Is there a work around to implement that kind of view. Well thanks for your help. I think i should drop the idea of having icons in my menu.