# Image Icon with Action Bar's Option Menu Item

Tags: android, android-actionbar, optionmenu

I want to display `Action Bar`'s Option Menu items with Image Icon like one we use in `Navigation Drawer Bar`.

Right now, My app option menu is showing as below :
 How do I display Image icon with Item 1, Item 2 etc.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PopupMenu with icons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15454995/popupmenu-with-icons)

Comment: I had the exact same "problem", this is what helped me (see the highest rated answer): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18374183/how-to-show-icons-in-overflow-menu-in-actionbar

Comment: @Ace_McIntosh, this post solved my issue. http://stackoverflow.com/a/20318161/3234665 Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Below code solved my issue. from this link : [How To show icons in Overflow menu in ActionBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18374183/how-to-show-icons-in-overflow-menu-in-actionbar)

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/empty"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_overflow"
    android:orderInCategory="101"
    android:showAsAction="always">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_show_ir_list"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_friendslist"
            android:showAsAction="always|withText"
            android:title="List"/>
    </menu>
</item>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution You are Looking for Copy this menu.`xml` And change icons and name as per your need in `mipmap`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/main_menu"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.ImageButton"
        android:icon="@mipmap/menu"
        android:orderInCategory="200"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="always">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/home"
                android:icon="@mipmap/home_menu"
                android:title="Home" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/edit_profile"
                android:icon="@mipmap/my_account"
                android:title="Profile" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/my_account"
                android:icon="@mipmap/my_account"
                android:title="My Account" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/messages"
                android:icon="@mipmap/message1"
                android:title="Messages" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/notification"
                android:icon="@mipmap/notification"
                android:title="Notifications" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/settings"
                android:icon="@mipmap/settings"
                android:title="Settings" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/logout"
                android:icon="@mipmap/logout"
                android:title="Logout" />
        </menu>

    </item>
</menu>
```

Then create `menu_main.xml` like this

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

Comment: then should i use `menu.xml` or `menu_main.xml` with MenuInflater ?

Comment: use menu.xml with menu inflater

Answer (score 0):

Same like a drawer view

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_item_attachment"
        android:checked="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_attachment"
        android:title="@string/nav_item_attachment" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_item_images"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_image"
        android:title="@string/nav_item_images" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_item_location"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_place"
        android:title="@string/nav_item_location" />
</group>

<item android:title="@string/nav_sub_menu">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_emoticon"
            android:title="@string/nav_sub_menu_item01" />
        <item
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_emoticon"
            android:title="@string/nav_sub_menu_item02" />
    </menu>
</item>
```

new menu.xml

---

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.yadav.bookedup.MainActivity">

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:title="@string/action_search"
    android:orderInCategory="200"
    android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_search_api_mtrl_alpha"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
    />

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_notf"
    android:title="Notification"
    android:orderInCategory="200"
    android:icon="@drawable/notf"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
    />


<item
    android:id="@+id/action_info"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="Info"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_image" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/req_clg"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="Request College"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_image" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/req_book"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="Request Books"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_image" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/share_app"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="Share the app"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_image" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/rate_app"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="Rate the App"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_terms"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="Terms &amp; Conditions"
    app:showAsAction="never" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_about"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="About Us"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_contct"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="Contact Us"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
```

Comment: I can't see any image icon with text.

Comment: You can add only particular items ... i will update my answer