# Actionbar Menu's item icons not shown properly upon RTL

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-support-library, android-menu

In order to be able to always show icons next to the text of each item in the menu, I used this [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52656128/8086424), as it was the easiest of the few methods mentioned online that out worked for me. The result was as follows:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
     MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
     inflater.inflate(R.menu.toolbar_menu,menu);

     if(menu instanceof MenuBuilder) {  //To display icon on overflow menu
          MenuBuilder m = (MenuBuilder) menu; 
          m.setOptionalIconsVisible(true);
     }

   return true;
}
```

---

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/sign_out_menu"
        android:title="@string/logout"
        android:icon="@drawable/logout_black_24dp"
        app:showAsAction="never" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/change_language_menu"
        android:title="@string/change_language"
        android:icon="@drawable/language_menu_24dp"
        app:showAsAction="never" />

</menu>
```

`[image]

**That's perfect!**

---

**The problem**: is when I change the language to one that is RTL!

It looks like this:
[image]

The Icons are cut off! Or, if you look closely, they are shifted too much to the Start/Right....Or everything is shifted too much to the Start/Right!

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: have you fixed this issue could you plz share the solution if you did solve it?

Answer (score 1):

A simple **trick** to solve this problem, till somebody comes up with a better solution:

The trick would be changing the values of the width and height of my vector drawables.

Example for one of them was **from this:**

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:autoMirrored="true"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF000000"
        android:pathData="M11.99,2C6.47,2 2,6.48 2,12s4.47,10 9.99,10C17.52,22 22,17.52 22,12S17.52,2 11.99,2zM18.92,8h-2.95c-0.32,-1.25 -0.78,-2.45 -1.38,-3.56 1.84,0.63 3.37,1.91 4.33,3.56zM12,4.04c0.83,1.2 1.48,2.53 1.91,3.96h-3.82c0.43,-1.43 1.08,-2.76 1.91,-3.96zM4.26,14C4.1,13.36 4,12.69 4,12s0.1,-1.36 0.26,-2h3.38c-0.08,0.66 -0.14,1.32 -0.14,2 0,0.68 0.06,1.34 0.14,2L4.26,14zM5.08,16h2.95c0.32,1.25 0.78,2.45 1.38,3.56 -1.84,-0.63 -3.37,-1.9 -4.33,-3.56zM8.03,8L5.08,8c0.96,-1.66 2.49,-2.93 4.33,-3.56C8.81,5.55 8.35,6.75 8.03,8zM12,19.96c-0.83,-1.2 -1.48,-2.53 -1.91,-3.96h3.82c-0.43,1.43 -1.08,2.76 -1.91,3.96zM14.34,14L9.66,14c-0.09,-0.66 -0.16,-1.32 -0.16,-2 0,-0.68 0.07,-1.35 0.16,-2h4.68c0.09,0.65 0.16,1.32 0.16,2 0,0.68 -0.07,1.34 -0.16,2zM14.59,19.56c0.6,-1.11 1.06,-2.31 1.38,-3.56h2.95c-0.96,1.65 -2.49,2.93 -4.33,3.56zM16.36,14c0.08,-0.66 0.14,-1.32 0.14,-2 0,-0.68 -0.06,-1.34 -0.14,-2h3.38c0.16,0.64 0.26,1.31 0.26,2s-0.1,1.36 -0.26,2h-3.38z" />
</vector>
```

**To this:**

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="50dp"
    android:height="50dp"
    android:autoMirrored="true"
    android:viewportWidth="22.0"
    android:viewportHeight="22.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF000000"
        android:pathData="M11.99,2C6.47,2 2,6.48 2,12s4.47,10 9.99,10C17.52,22 22,17.52 22,12S17.52,2 11.99,2zM18.92,8h-2.95c-0.32,-1.25 -0.78,-2.45 -1.38,-3.56 1.84,0.63 3.37,1.91 4.33,3.56zM12,4.04c0.83,1.2 1.48,2.53 1.91,3.96h-3.82c0.43,-1.43 1.08,-2.76 1.91,-3.96zM4.26,14C4.1,13.36 4,12.69 4,12s0.1,-1.36 0.26,-2h3.38c-0.08,0.66 -0.14,1.32 -0.14,2 0,0.68 0.06,1.34 0.14,2L4.26,14zM5.08,16h2.95c0.32,1.25 0.78,2.45 1.38,3.56 -1.84,-0.63 -3.37,-1.9 -4.33,-3.56zM8.03,8L5.08,8c0.96,-1.66 2.49,-2.93 4.33,-3.56C8.81,5.55 8.35,6.75 8.03,8zM12,19.96c-0.83,-1.2 -1.48,-2.53 -1.91,-3.96h3.82c-0.43,1.43 -1.08,2.76 -1.91,3.96zM14.34,14L9.66,14c-0.09,-0.66 -0.16,-1.32 -0.16,-2 0,-0.68 0.07,-1.35 0.16,-2h4.68c0.09,0.65 0.16,1.32 0.16,2 0,0.68 -0.07,1.34 -0.16,2zM14.59,19.56c0.6,-1.11 1.06,-2.31 1.38,-3.56h2.95c-0.96,1.65 -2.49,2.93 -4.33,3.56zM16.36,14c0.08,-0.66 0.14,-1.32 0.14,-2 0,-0.68 -0.06,-1.34 -0.14,-2h3.38c0.16,0.64 0.26,1.31 0.26,2s-0.1,1.36 -0.26,2h-3.38z" />
</vector>
```

I got the values through lots of trials and errors, till the sizes made sense. And both icons used different values for width and height in order to adjust properly.

The results are as follows:
[image]

With RTL: [image]

I can also save the width and height values in the string.xml as to apply the new dimensions only upon language change.

Not perfect though!

Comment: Nice one. But the icon is larger now. What if I dont want to large them?