# SpannableString with space on top and bottom of just Word betwenn anothers

Tags: android, kotlin, layout, textview, spannablestring

Hi Guys ? So I have a one TextView and I have a Word of value that I have to set some styles only on value, like

the problem is, I need to put space on top and bottom of this value inside the textview to be it a little separeted the rest of String.

I need to let it like that

[image: Image of what I nedd]

My code now is this

```
private fun configTitleSpan(
    title: String,
    textToSpanValue: String
): SpannableString {
    val startIndex = title.indexOf(textToSpanValue)
    val endIndex = title.indexOf(textToSpanValue).plus(textToSpanValue.length)
    if (startIndex <= 0 || endIndex <= 0) return title.toSpan()

    return SpannableString(title)
        .apply {
            setSpan(
                RelativeSizeSpan(SIZE_SPAN),
                startIndex,
                endIndex,
                Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
            )
        }
        .apply {
            setSpan(
                TypefaceSpan(DEFAULT_FONT_STYLE),
                startIndex,
                endIndex,
                Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
            )
        }
        .apply {
            setSpan(
                MarginTopBottomSpan(HEIGHT_SIZE_SPAN, HEIGHT_SIZE_SPAN),
                startIndex,
                endIndex,
                Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
            )
        }
}
```

I can put the value formatted but the space on top and bottom that I need I can`t put it.

Answer (score 0):

I can solve it following this answer, I made some adjusts and works fine.
[Using LineHeightSpan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11120208/9090281)

```
private class MarginTopBottomSpan(
    private val topMargin: Int,
    private val bottomMargin: Int
) : LineHeightSpan {

    override fun chooseHeight(
        text: CharSequence,
        start: Int,
        end: Int,
        spanstartv: Int,
        v: Int,
        fm: FontMetricsInt
    ) {
        fm.bottom += bottomMargin
        fm.descent += bottomMargin
        fm.top += topMargin * VALUE_NEGATIVE
        fm.ascent += topMargin * VALUE_NEGATIVE
    }

    companion object {

        private const val VALUE_NEGATIVE = -1
    }
}
```